# this profile cannot be installed on devices ?? iPhone distribution ... any ideas

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting a "new" kind of error in the provisioning hell from iPhone.  Does anyone have an idea what's going on .. because reinstalling , redownloading of the profile doesn't work.

I've uploaded a screenshot.

http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1559/picture15f.png

So the part where it says cannot be installed on devices?

Answer (score 2):

If that is your distribution certificate (as your title implies) then the error message is correct. Distribution certificates are only for submitting applications to Apple for review.

Instead you will want to install a development certificate on your phone. That will allow you to load your phone with your own code for testing before submitting to Apple.

Comment: Yep, I wouldn't call this a "hell", it's pretty clear about what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely call it hell.  Signing my first app for Apple is taking 100 times longer than it took for Android.  I'm not quite sure why such tight security is needed.  I've been spending an entire day on this security stuff.  I'm sure once I figure it out it won't be too horrible, but this is a real pain so far.